# Vertical Viewpager with different fragment heights?

Tags: android, fragment, vertical-scrolling

I have a vertical Viewpager in my App that swipe through fragments vertically. Is there an implementation that will allow me to have fragments with different layout_heights to appear one after another (just like listview)?

I have already tried following:

```
verticalViewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
verticalViewPager.setPageMargin(10);
```

But this technique sets padding for entire viewpager. I need padding to be set for individual fragments, so that they appear one-after-another with a small gap (eg. 10dp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it using following method in Adapter

```
@Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    return (0-1];
}
```